# Sequelize .set error, .set is not a function

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, join, sequelize.js

I am trying to set up a belongsTo and hasMany association which seems to be working, but when I run .set I am getting the error `fighterData.setUsers is not a function`. The dialect is mySql. Here is my code:

```
Fighters.belongsTo(Users)
Users.hasMany(Fighters);

Users.sync()
Fighters.sync()
//creates the table if it doesn't exist

const insertFighter = function(obj, sessId) {
  return Fighters.create(obj, {returning: true}).then((fighterData) => {
    //console.log('inserted a fighter \n', fighterData);
    return Users.findOne({
      where: {
        id: sessId
      }
    }).then((userData) => {
      //console.log('fighterData in findOne promise \n', fighterData)
      return fighterData.setUsers(userData)
    }).then((success)=> {
      console.log('user fighter join success')
      return
    }).catch((err)=> {
      console.log('user fighter join error \n', err)
      return
    })
  }).catch((err)=> {
    console.log('error inserting fighter \n', err);
  })
}
```

The error that's logging is `user fighter join error`.
interestingly, `userData.setFighters(fighterData)` works successfully, but that is not what I need

***EDIT***

This is what fighterData is:

```
fighterData in findOne promise 
 Fighters {
  dataValues:
   { id: 7,
     name: 'Gilbert Burns',
     image:
      'https://www.sherdog.com/image_crop/200/300/_images/fighter/20140806063215_IMG_8432.JPG',
     next_opponent: 'Kamaru Usman',
     next_fight: 'July 11, 2020 ',
     style: 'mma',
     updatedAt: 2020-06-17T06:00:40.368Z,
     createdAt: 2020-06-17T06:00:40.368Z },
  _previousDataValues:
   { name: 'Gilbert Burns',
     image:
      'https://www.sherdog.com/image_crop/200/300/_images/fighter/20140806063215_IMG_8432.JPG',
     next_opponent: 'Kamaru Usman',
     next_fight: 'July 11, 2020 ',
     style: 'mma',
     id: 7,
     createdAt: 2020-06-17T06:00:40.368Z,
     updatedAt: 2020-06-17T06:00:40.368Z,
     UserId: undefined },
  _changed:
   { name: false,
     image: false,
     next_opponent: false,
     next_fight: false,
     style: false,
     id: false,
     createdAt: false,
     updatedAt: false,
     UserId: false },
  _modelOptions:
   { timestamps: true,
     validate: {},
     freezeTableName: false,
     underscored: false,
     paranoid: false,
     rejectOnEmpty: false,
     whereCollection: null,
     schema: null,
     schemaDelimiter: '',
     defaultScope: {},
     scopes: {},
     indexes: [],
     name: { plural: 'Fighters', singular: 'Fighter' },
     omitNull: false,
     sequelize:
      Sequelize {
        options: [Object],
        config: [Object],
        dialect: [MysqlDialect],
        queryInterface: [QueryInterface],
        models: [Object],
        modelManager: [ModelManager],
        connectionManager: [ConnectionManager],
        importCache: {} },
     hooks: {} },
  _options:
   { isNewRecord: true,
     _schema: null,
     _schemaDelimiter: '',
     attributes: undefined,
     include: undefined,
     raw: undefined,
     silent: undefined },
  isNewRecord: false }
```

This is returned from entering one fighter's information into the database.

Comment: Where do you define "fighterData"?

Comment: @OscarVelandia fighterData is the model returned in the promise chain from running `Fighters.create()`

Comment: If you do console.log of fighterData what do you get?

Comment: @OscarVelandia
I made an edit to the OP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with the naming of your models.

Sequelize expects your models to be named in singular form (`User` instead of `Users`), so it's getting confused with what it should name the generated setter and getter methods for your association.

If you try `fighterData.setUser(userData)` instead of `fighterData.setUsers(userData)`, it should work.

If you you want to use `setUsers` instead, you will have to make adjustments to your model to tell Sequelize to use `Users` as the singular form of `User`:

```
Users.init({
    sessId: Sequelize.STRING
 }, {
    sequelize: sequelize,
    name: {
        singular: 'users'
    }
});
```

You can overwrite the plural form the same way as well.

You can read more about this here: [Sequelize naming strategy](https://sequelize.org/v5/manual/associations.html#naming-strategy)